# Why is my table background image not showing in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, image, html-table

Why is my table row background image not appearing in Wordpress.

Is the stylesheet for the theme suppressing it in some way and if so, how can one override that to make the image show, or is there some other fault causing it not to appear?

Note the other image in the table does display properly so the path to the files seems to work ok.

```
<table width="250" height="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<tr>
    <td WIDTH="250" HEIGHT="82" colspan="3"><img src="/wp-content/plugins/xxxxxxwidget/image1.png">
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="background-image:url(/wp-content/plugins/xxxxxxwidget/image2.png) no-repeat center;" WIDTH="250" HEIGHT="45" colspan="3">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem might be without all of the code.  Do you have a publicly visible site for us to inspect?  If not, could you paste your code into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Is the `background-image` for the table cells appearing over the top of the `tr`'s `background-image`? Have you tried setting `background-color: transparent;` on the `td`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
background-image:url(/wp-content/plugins/xxxxxxwidget/image2.png) no-repeat center;
```

to

```
background:url(/wp-content/plugins/xxxxxxwidget/image2.png) no-repeat center;
```

Answer (score 1):

add `position:absolute;` to your table style.